# How to add owner to a Distribution Group using Microsoft Graph Rest Api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, exchange-server

I am using this one to add owner to a Distribution group

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/owners/$ref
Content-type: application/json
{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}"
}
```

But got this error:

```
[ERROR] Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "Web Exception Summary: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request., Web Exception Details: {"error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":"Cannot Update a mail-enabled security groups and or distribution list."
```

I can confirm that the group id, user id and the api is correct. It seems to be the problem with Distribution Group only.

Comment: It seems like mail `mail-enabled security groups and or distribution list` are not manageable through Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

First, I succeeded to call the api to add a user to my security group.

You may need to check the group id and user id here.

For user id, pls go to azure ad-> choose Users blade-> find your user-> click the user and see Profile-> get Object ID in the profile page.

For group id, go to azure ad-> choose Groups blade-> find your group-> click the group and reached the overview page-> get Object Id as well.

Then you may need to check the way you generate the access token. You may check if your token has correct api permission mentioned in [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-owners?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions). Copy your token and decode it in jwt.io, for application permission, check the `roles` claim if contains `Group.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All`, and for delegate permission, check the `scp` claim if contains `Group.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All, Directory.AccessAsUser.All`.

[image]

Comment: Thank for your reply, as confirm from microsoft graph soi doesn't support distribution group yet (which relates to exchange online service), I use set-distributiongroup exo command and it works now

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir and it sounds good that it worked with `set-distributiongroup exo command` : )